# How to give space between horizontal divs?

Tags: html, css

I have tried giving `margin` for `div` but the one `div` box goes to next line. How to solve that?

https://jsfiddle.net/2h25xbna/

I want it like this-
[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course4/master/assignments/assignment2/images/desktop.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cqlK.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>assignment</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device, initial-scale=1"  >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Trending Languages</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" ><p id="py">python</p><br><p>The computing industry progresses in two mostly independent cycles: financial and product cycles. There has been a lot of handwringing lately about where we are in the financial cycle. Financial markets get a lot of attention. </p></div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 "><p id="js">Javascript</p><br><p>The computing industry progresses in two mostly independent cycles: financial and product cycles. There has been a lot of handwringing lately about where we are in the financial cycle. Financial markets get a lot of attention.</p></div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12" ><p id="ru">ruby</p><br><p>The computing industry progresses in two mostly independent cycles: financial and product cycles. There has been a lot of handwringing lately about where we are in the financial cycle. Financial markets get a lot of attention. </p></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Also when screen pixels goes below 768px boundary disappears,why? how to solve that.I also want to give border for rightmost text inside the box. I tried giving using id but it didn't work.

```
#py{
      background-color: #ff9999;
      float: right;
      clear: left;
      position: relative;
      top: -15px
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border: 2px;
}
```

Comment: can you show your html too?

Comment: you need to add your complete css code too

Comment: Do you mean you want a white space between python and javascript divs?

Comment: I want space between all three divs.

Comment: @KajalWaldiya I'm added an answer below ,don't forget to tick it if it's useful :p

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed some styles.
add

```
.row{
  display:flex;
  }
.col-lg-4{
  margin:10px;
  border:2px solid #000;
  }
```

to your style sheet it work's fine.I'm added the snippet below.

```css
.rw{
  display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
.col{
  background-color: gray;
  margin:10px;
  border:2px solid #000;
  }
.title {
    background-color: #ff9999;
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    right: -2px;
}
#js{
  background-color: #cc0000;
  color: white;
}
#ru{
  background-color: #ff9966;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>assignment</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device, initial-scale=1"  >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Trending Languages</h1>
<div class="rw">
  <div class="col" ><p id="py" class="title">python</p><br><p>The computing industry progresses in two mostly independent cycles: financial and product cycles. There has been a lot of handwringing lately about where we are in the financial cycle. Financial markets get a lot of attention. </p></div>

  <div class="col "><p id="js" class="title">Javascript</p><br><p>The computing industry progresses in two mostly independent cycles: financial and product cycles. There has been a lot of handwringing lately about where we are in the financial cycle. Financial markets get a lot of attention.</p></div>
  <div class="col" ><p id="ru" class="title">ruby</p><br><p>The computing industry progresses in two mostly independent cycles: financial and product cycles. There has been a lot of handwringing lately about where we are in the financial cycle. Financial markets get a lot of attention. </p></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you but media queries doesn't seem to work after applying these style.

Comment: that is why I'm asking for your complete css code,you need to add your media query part also

Comment: i have provided link in the question.

Comment: @kajal that is probably happened because you mix up your old code with this.try to comment your old code part and try this.I'm added  little modifications

Answer (score -1):

Use `display:flex;` or `display:inline-block;` like this

```
.row {
    display:flex;
    // your extra css
}
```

Then give padding for each `col`